# The name XXXX does not exist in the current context-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code

```
function pickdet(Id) {
        //alert(Id);
        var dd = Id;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/PVSigns1/GetDetails",
            data: { 'Id' : Id },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert('i dey here')
                var row = "";
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    //row += "<tr><td>" + item.VitalSigns.Sign + "</td><td>" + item.SignValue + "</td><td> <input type= 'button'  onclick= location.href = + '<Url.Action("Create", "PVSigns1", new { Id = item.PVSignId }) ' />" + "</td></tr>";
                    row += "<tr><td>" + item.VitalSigns.Sign + "</td><td>" + item.SignValue +
                        "</td><td> <button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' onclick = '@Url.Action("Create","PVSigns1", new { Id = item.PVSignId })'> <i class='fa fa-edit fa-lg'></i> Edit</button></td></tr>";
                });
                $("#pvv").html(row);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $("#pvv").html('Nothing to show <br /> <p />' + result );
            }
        });
    }
```

The issue is it points at the at eh item and complains "the name item does not exist in the current context". The error is the occurs after the @Url.Action, others before that are ok.

```
"</td><td> <button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' onclick = '@Url.Action("Create","PVSigns1", new { Id = item.PVSignId })'> <i class='fa fa-edit fa-lg'></i> Edit</button></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line,

> @Url.Action("Create","PVSigns1", new { Id = item.PVSignId })

But in your code, `item` is a javascript variable  inside your loop. **you cannot pass a javascript variable to the `Url.Action` method as `Url.Action` code will be executed way before in the server**(At that time it does not have any idea about the future ajax call the page is going to make !!!)

The solution is to use another overload of `Url.Action` to build the base url to the Create action method and append the javascript variable property and use that.

Also, setting the `onclick` event to a url might not work. You might consider adding a `click` event to the button and redirect to the url. You may keep the url in html 5 data attribute.

```
 var baseLink='@Url.Action("Create","PVSigns1")';
 $.each(data, function (index, item) {
    var link=baseLink+item.PVSignId; 
    row += "<tr><td>" + item.VitalSigns.Sign + "</td><td>" + item.SignValue +
       "</td><td> <button class='editBtn' data-url='"+link+"'>
                              <i class='fa fa-edit fa-lg'></i> Edit</button></td></tr>";
 });
```

and have some jQuery code to listen to the click event on this button and redirect to the url in our data attribute

```
$(function(){

  $("button.editBtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href=$(this).attr("url");
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Shyju this also works like charm.  Problem is that the link doesn't work, and the table doesn't have a source when you look at page source. That is the table header is rendered but the body isn't. From the webpage you see the full table header and body. What could be the problem.

Comment: Are you getting an array of item in `data`, Then it should add items to the table body unless you have a javascript error in your page. Inspect your browser console. The link should work as long as you set the `data-url` value and have the js code to handle the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a quote problem, and you try to mix c# with javascript variables.

You could rather try something like

```
success: function (data) {

       var row = "";
       //the "base url"
       var url = '@Url.Action("Create","PVSigns1")' + '?Id=';
       $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            //add the id value here
            var clickUrl= url +item.PVSignId;
            row += "<tr><td>" + item.VitalSigns.Sign + "</td><td>" + item.SignValue +
                    "</td><td> <button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' onclick = '" + clickUrl +"'> <i class='fa fa-edit fa-lg'></i> Edit</button></td></tr>";
            });
            $("#pvv").html(row);
        },
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very correct.  The only issue here is, when the page is rendered, and the edit link in clicked, the edit page is not loaded, also I looked at the page source, there is no markup for the table, so how does the table appear?

Comment: For this part, you should look at the more complete Shyju's answer

Answer (score 0):

JS syntax errors:

```
"</td><td> <button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' onclick = '@Url.Action("Create","PVSigns1", new { Id = item.PVSignId })'> <i class='fa fa-
^--start string                                                          ^--end string
```

You cannot embed "bare" quotes of the same type you use to delimit a string, within that string. They must be escaped:

```
.... @Url.Action(\"Create\", \"PVSigns1\" ...
```

Comment: I think there's also a problem with `new { Id = item.PVSignId }`, as item is a js variable. So it can't be used in a c# method. The url should be builded another way...